# Concurrent URL fetching loops with python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, gevent, curio

I need to run around 500 concurrent **loops**. Each loop will sequentially fetch a paginated REST endpoint until it reaches the last page of each of the 500 endpoints. Some of these loops have just 5 to 10 pages so it will finish quickly, but others have 100s of pages.

The problem is that **I need to put this URL fetching in a sequential, blocking loop** because each page has to be fetched in order due to API limitations (The API will **throw an error** if I fetch page 7, then page 5 for instance). So, the unit of parallelism here are each loop, not each URL fetching inside a loop.

There is no heavy computation done anywhere. Just fetch a page, and throw the raw content into a kafka topic. I'm open to any suggestion except multi-process dependent on many cores. AsyncIO, Gevent, Multithreading...

**Edit 1:**

<del>The actual problem is that if I use **aiohttp** to fetch each page inside each loop asynchronously, I have no guarantees that page 2 will be fetched after page 1. The request will be initiated in the correct sequence, but there is absolutely no guarantee that the request will arrive and be processed at the endpoint in the correct sequence.</del>

**Edit 2:**

As pointed by user4815162342 aiohttp should work

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far and what specific problem are you having? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48767597/edit) your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In asyncio you can start in parallel as many loops as there are endpoints, and wait for all of them to finish. Each loop will use aiohttp to fetch endpoint pages sequentially. For example:

```
async def download_loop(session, endpoint):
    for i in itertools.count(1):
        try:
            async with session.get(endpoint, params={'page': str(i)}) as resp:
                content = await resp.read()
        except aiohttp.ClientResponseError:
            break   # no more pages
        # do something with the response content

async def download(endpoints):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        # Start all loops in parallel and wait for them to finish.
        # This will start as many loops as there are endpoints.
        await asyncio.wait([download_loop(session, endpoint)
                            for endpoint in endpoints])

# for testing:
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(download(['http://endpoint1', 'http://endpoint2', ...]))
```

Production code would probably also catch `aiohttp.ClientConnectionError` and re-try that URL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this solution will not work because if I use aiohttp to fetch the pages asynchronously, I have no guarantees that page 2 will be fetched after page 1. The request will be **initiated** in the correct sequence, but there is absolutely no guarantee that the request will arrive and be processed at the endpoint in the correct sequence. This is the actual problem of the original question.

Comment: @DanielFerreiraJorge They are not fetched asynchronously - each page of an endpoint is fetched in sequence, as guaranteed by the use of `await` inside the `for` loop. In other words, the next iteration of the loop will commence only after the response for the previous one is fully received. The only truly asynchronous communication happens at the level of *loops*, but that was explicitly allowed (in fact requested) in the question.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Hi @user4815162342 when I run this code, I get an error `TypeError: expect a list of futures, not generator`, in the `loop.run_until_complete`... could you help me? (I included real endpoints)

Comment: @DanielFerreiraJorge Oops, it seems that `asyncio.wait` doesn't like receiving a generator expression. I've now amended the answer to pass it a list instead.

Comment: @DanielFerreiraJorge Great! Good luck with asyncio.